# remove quotes from the variable value in python

Tags: python

I pull data from a repository where the server name is like this:

```
name=example%09
```

I need to replace the %. I am doing this:

```
name=re.sub("\%.*$","",name)
```

when I try to use name variable again, it has double quotes at the begging of the name, like this:

print name, it prints out like this:

```
"example
```

How would I get rid of " from the beginning in python?

```
name="example%09"
name=re.sub("\%.*$","",name)
print Metric,int(time.time()),p.Val,"vSphereGuest="+name,"source=vSphereGuest","dc=dc1"

vSphereGuest.cpuUsageMhz 1417040919 0 vSphereGuest="example source=vSphereGuest dc=dc1
```

Comment: So, you're trying to remove everything from `'%'` to the end of the string?  `name.split('%')[0]` seems like it would work . . .

Comment: why use regular expression when string manipulation is so much easier in this case!

Comment: I'm not seeing it. ```>>> re.sub("\%.*$","",name) Out: 'example'```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `string.replace("%", "")`.

```
name = "example%09"
name = name.replace("%", "")
```

If you want to get the value of the string before the `%`, use `string.split("%")`, then grab the index you need.

```
name = "example%09"
name = name.split("%")[0] #gets the 0 index of the list created when using `string.split()`
```

To replace any quotes that might appear in the string you can use `string.replace('"', '')`

```
name = "example%09"
if '"' in name:
    name = name.replace('"', '')
```

Comment: I followed this but when I print out the variable name, it cannot have quotes around it, how would I do that?

Comment: @user1471980, I updated the answer.  Just use `string.replace('"', '')`